# How does this recursive power set algorithm work?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, combinations

I've discovered and am trying to understand power sets, specifically how to calculate the power sets of a set. I found the [algorithm's description](http://www.ecst.csuchico.edu/~akeuneke/foo/csci356/notes/ch1/solutions/recursionSol.html), which concluded with this:

$$P\left(S\right) = P\left(S-\left\{e_i\right\}\right) \cup\left\{\left\{e_i\right\}\cup P\left(S-\left\{e_i\right\}\right)\right\}$$

Where $e_i$ is any element of $P$. I *think* I understand what this means, but it doesn't seem to work. It looks like it says to first perform a union of sets and then another union with one of them, which is going to be the same as the first union. Regardless of the recursive nature, just using two sets, doesn't $x \cup \left\{y \cup x\right\} = y \cup x$?

Comment: The displayed equation is not correct. It should be (writing $e$ for $e_i$) $$\mathcal P(S)=\mathcal P(S\smallsetminus\{e\})\cup\{\{e\}\cup A:A\in\mathcal P(S\smallsetminus\{e\})\}.$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $e_i \in S$, "$P(S - \{e_i\})$" is the powerset of $S$ with $e_i$ removed.  It is a collection of sets, each of which is a subset of $S - \{e_i\}$ and so is a subset of $S$ not containing $e_i$.

"$\{\{e_i\} \cup P(S - \{e_i\})\}$" is a bit malformed.  Better would be
$$  \left\{ \{e_i\} \cup p : p \in P(S - \{e_i\}) \right\} \text{,}  $$
the collection of subsets of $S - \{e_i\}$ with $e_i$ put back in.

Then take the union of the first collection (subsets without $e_i$) and the second collection (subsets with $e_i$) to get the powerset of $S$.

Regarding "$x \cup \{y \cup x\} = y \cup x$": No.

- $y \cup x$ is the set containing all the elements of $x$ and $y$.
- $\{y \cup x\}$ is the set of one element, which element is the set containing all the elements of $x$ and $y$.
- $x \cup \{y \cup x\}$ is a set containing all the elements of $x$ and one more element, which element is the set containing all the elements of $x$ and $y$ (assuming this one element isn't already an element of $x$).

Comment: Thank you. You're explanation of $x \cup \left\{y \cup x \right\}$ was very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The formula in the link you cite is wrong. A correct formula along these lines would be:

$$
P(S) = P(S - \{e_i\}) \cup \{A \mid \exists B \in P(S - \{e_i\})\cdot A = \{e_i\}\cup B\}
$$

I.e., to form the set $P(S)$ of subsets of $S$, you include each subset of $S-\{e_i\}$ (for some $e_i \in S$) and each set that can be formed by adding $e_i$ to a subset of $S-\{e_i\}$.

Comment: Oops! That was a typo. I've fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is easier and more constructive 
to write $P(S \cup \{x\}) = P(S) \cup \{ A \cup \{x\} \}_{A \in P(S)}$